# How can I initialize a multidimensional array of n dimensions where n is the input from a user in C?

Tags: c, multidimensional-array

I have to take the input N from the user. Then I have to create an array of N dimensions. For example if N=4 then`array[][][][]` and when N=6 then `array[][][][][][]`.

Comment: You can't. You will need to implement a dynamic data structure to handle it.

Comment: And even if you could, you would need not just the number of dimensions, but also the extent of each dimension.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Please give some example .

Comment: `struct multidim { int dimensions; int* data }`. And a bunch of functions to work with it.

Comment: @FibonacciCoder May I ask why?

Comment: How are you planning to write the code to access an array element when the array has 3 dimensions, or 5 dimensions?  How will you handle writing loops to iterate over 3, or 5, dimensions?  Are you sure that what you're trying to do makes sense?

Comment: @CoolGuy there is a question on hacker rank which goes like this "You are situated in an N
N
 dimensional grid at position (x1,x2,...,xN)
x
1
x
2
x
N
. The dimensions of the grid are (D1,D2,...DN)
D
1
D
2
D
N
. In one step, you can walk one step ahead or behind in any one of the N
N
 dimensions. (So there are always 2×N
2
N
 possible different moves). In how many ways can you take M
M
 steps such that you do not leave the grid at any point? You leave the grid if at any point xi
x
i
, either xi≤0
x
i
0
 or xi>Di
x
i
D
i
. I have done it using recurssion but it is giving timeout .

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to create an array whose size is to be determined at runtime ("dynamically"), you should use one of the standard C functions for dynamic memory allocation, such as `calloc()` which allocates memory and zero-initializes it.

Here's an example for a one-dimensional array:

```
int ii, entries = 0;
scanf("%d", &entries);
float *data = calloc(entries, sizeof(float));

/* load values into the memory addressed by data, as if it were an array */
for (ii=0; ii<entries, ii++) {
  printf("Enter entry %d: \n", ii);
  scanf("%g", &(data[ii])); /* &(data[ii]) is equivalent to data + ii */
}
```